# wxWidgets minimal.cpp liner error in function `wxString::ImplStr(char const*, wxMBConv const&)'

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, cygwin, wxwidgets

Getting this error when compiling and linking the minimal.cpp file from the samples directory

```
g++ -o "SampleMinimal" ./src/minimal.o   -lwx_mswu_xrc-3.0-x86_64-w64-mingw32 -lwx_mswu_webview-3.0-x86_64-w64-mingw32 -lwx_mswu_html-3.0-x86_64-w64-mingw32 -lwx_mswu_qa-3.0-x86_64-w64-mingw32 -lwx_mswu_adv-3.0-x86_64-w64-mingw32 -lwx_mswu_core-3.0-x86_64-w64-mingw32 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.0-x86_64-w64-mingw32 -lwx_baseu_net-3.0-x86_64-w64-mingw32 -lwx_baseu-3.0-x86_64-w64-mingw32 -L/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib -Wl,--subsystem,windows -mwindows -Wl,--enable-auto-import
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: ./src/minimal.o: in function `wxString::ImplStr(char const*, wxMBConv const&)':
/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/wx-3.0/wx/string.h:477: undefined reference to `wxString::ConvertStr(char const*, unsigned long, wxMBConv const&)'
/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/wx-3.0/wx/string.h:477:(.text$_ZN8wxString7ImplStrEPKcRK8wxMBConv[_ZN8wxString7ImplStrEPKcRK8wxMBConv]+0x3a): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `wxString::ConvertStr(char const*, unsigned long, wxMBConv const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Successfully creating object file.

Compiler command line:

```
g++ -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL -D__WXMSW__ -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/wx/include/x86_64-w64-mingw32-msw-unicode-3.0 -I"/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/wx-3.0" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/minimal.d" -MT"src/minimal.o" -o "src/minimal.o" "../src/minimal.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/minimal.cpp
```

Linker command line:

```
g++ -o "SampleMinimal" ./src/minimal.o   -lwx_mswu_xrc-3.0-x86_64-w64-mingw32 -lwx_mswu_webview-3.0-x86_64-w64-mingw32 -lwx_mswu_html-3.0-x86_64-w64-mingw32 -lwx_mswu_qa-3.0-x86_64-w64-mingw32 -lwx_mswu_adv-3.0-x86_64-w64-mingw32 -lwx_mswu_core-3.0-x86_64-w64-mingw32 -lwx_baseu_xml-3.0-x86_64-w64-mingw32 -lwx_baseu_net-3.0-x86_64-w64-mingw32 -lwx_baseu-3.0-x86_64-w64-mingw32 -L/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib -Wl,--subsystem,windows -mwindows -Wl,--enable-auto-import
```

Comment: Are you using MSYS 1 or MSYS 2? Did you build the libraries yourself or using the pre-built ones?

Comment: Igor thanks for answering not sure the difference between MSYS 1 and MSYS 2. I installed MinGw and the wxWidget libraries from inside cygwin. So I am using pre-built ones. How can I tell which MSYS I have?  uname -a shows: CYGWIN_NT-10.0 ENGWSL201908-16 3.1.4(0.340/5/3) 2020-02-19 08:49 x86_64 Cygwin.

Comment: Sorry but it's really not clear at all what are you doing and why are you showing these compiler/linker command lines. Where are they coming from? You don't seem to be using neither `samples/minimal/makefile.unx` nor configure-generated `samples/minimal/Makefile`, so how did you end up with them?

Also, are you really trying to build Cygwin version of the library? If so, do you have any good reasons for doing it? If not, I *strongly* recommend building using one of MinGW compilers instead.

Comment: @JeffreyJacobs, it is possible you downloaded an incompatible verion of wxWidgets that was built with different compiler that you are using. The best way is as Vadim suggested is to build the library yourself using configure and then use it in your own project.

Comment: Sorry Igor StackOverflow newbie. I was using Eclipse to compile and link. I had created a tag for Eclipse, Cygwin, and wxWidgets so I thought it was clear that Eclipse is how the compiler and linker commands were created. I had sucked down the source code earlier but failed to compile so after getting the binaries, I imported into Eclipse the minimal.cpp code found in the wxWidget source. You can see below that I was able to get the code to build and run. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You're apparently compiling `minimal` sample in debug mode, see `-g3` flag, then attempting to link against release `mswu` libs.

So either change the sample compilation to release mode, or change the linker command to use `mswud` debug libs.

Comment: Catalin thanks for the help.  I should have realized I was not using debug libraries. I believe I only installed the release binaries in Cygwin so I changed the Eclipse build configuration to release. I am still seeing this error   ./src/minimal.o:minimal.cpp:(.text+0x145): undefined reference to `wxString::ConvertStr(char const*, unsigned long, wxMBConv const&)' <br> 08:25:12 Build Failed. 18 errors, 0 warnings. (took 7s.120ms)  All 18 errrors are the same undefined reference to wxString::ConvertStr.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by making Command: x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ for both the GCC C++ compiler and the MinGW C++ Linker in the C/C++ build settings in Eclipse. I thought this was done automatically by selecting the MinGW tool chain. Many thanks to Catalin for pointing out that I was linking against release libraries in the debug build configuration. His answer to make my build configuration release got me that one step further. Thanks!